# Main page text size change

Tags: support

Has a change been made to the default text size on the Sci-fi main site? I can't see any setting that I've changed, but everything is at a smaller size there than any other part of the stack exchange network, including here on meta.

Edit

Definitely not the zoom, I've got a default chrome install with no plugins in the way. But, the issue goes away in both Firefox and Chrome incognito, which suggests a personal setting somewhere...

Comment: What browser, etc are you using? Have you accidentally used the [zoom function](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on [your browser](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-text-size-mozilla-firefox-41425.html) to make the text smaller/larger?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**  For me at least this turns out to be a user (me) error.  The Stylus plugin is enforcing the older SE layout which used a 1.3 line-height instead of 1.5.  In fact [I railed against a 1.5 line height](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55372530#55372530) at the time.

I tracked down the rogue source of the `line-height: 1.3 !important;` to an inline style applied to the page *after* it was fetched, and found the plug-in modifying the page.

---

There does in fact appear to be something going on with the `line-height` attribute.  Other text sizing attributes appear to be unchanged, but I'm seeing a line-height of 19.5px for SF&F, but 22.5px for meta.scifi and other SE sites.

22.5px appears to be what would be expected based on the CSS:

```
.s-prose {
    --s-prose-line-height: 1.5;
    --s-prose-spacing: 1.1em;
    --s-prose-spacing-condensed: calc(var(--s-prose-spacing) / 2);
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: var(--s-prose-line-height);
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```
<div class="s-prose js-post-body" itemprop="text">
                
<p>Has a change been made to the default text size on the Sci-fi main site? I can't see any setting that I've changed, but everything is at a smaller size there than any other part of the stack exchange network, including here on meta.</p>
    </div>
```

I'm not sure where the 19.5 is coming from.